# How can I solve this error in WebGL Unity game?

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

### **I have no idea why I'm getting this error. After building my project in WebGL and launching it in itch.io game window (in Chrome) it displays this message, the game can't run:**

> > An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was: uncaught
> >     exception: abort(180) at jsStackTrace
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22313) stackTrace
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22484)
> >     onAbort@file:///C:/Users/wujtm_000/Desktop/WebGL/Build/UnityLoader.js:4:11118
> >     abort (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:483539)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[45753]:0xda48f7
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[22089]:0x9023d7)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[24498]:0x95f899
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[22992]:0x93c06c)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[45533]:0xda3cc0 UnityModule
> >     [UnityModule/Module.dynCall_iiiii]
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:458801) invoke_iiiii
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:335855)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[43654]:0xd4f185
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[43125]:0xd37edc)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[4225]:0x18b90c
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[4224]:0x18b835)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10198]:0x3c205a
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10182]:0x3c0d4e)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[12109]:0x4b637b
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[12108]:0x4b6095)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10577]:0x3ed282
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10288]:0x3caa9b)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10288]:0x3caab0
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10283]:0x3ca5ba)
> >     @blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[10276]:0x3c881e
> >     (blob:null/721358bf-caaa-4408-babf-350932a4b11a line 8 >
> >     WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[45547]:0xda3ef2) UnityModule
> >     [UnityModule/Module.dynCall_v]
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:467249) browserIterationFunc
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:175900) runIter
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:178973) Browser_mainLoop_runner
> >     (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:177435)

[image: argh..]

### **The web console error:**

> Invoking error handler due to Uncaught abort(180) at Error
>       at jsStackTrace (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22313)
>       at stackTrace [Object.stackTrace] (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22484)
>       at Object.onAbort (https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/2312897/WebGL/Build/UnityLoader.js:4:11118)
>       at abort (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:483549)
>       at :wasm-function[45753]:0xda48f7
>       at :wasm-function[22089]:0x9023d7
>       at :wasm-function[24498]:0x95f899
>       at :wasm-function[22992]:0x93c06c
>       at dynCall_iiiii (:wasm-function[45533]:0xda3cc0)
>       at dynCall_iiiii [Object.dynCall_iiiii] (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:458801)
>       at invoke_iiiii (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:335871)
>       at :wasm-function[43654]:0xd4f185
>       at :wasm-function[43125]:0xd37edc
>       at :wasm-function[4225]:0x18b90c
>       at :wasm-function[4224]:0x18b835
>       at :wasm-function[10198]:0x3c205a
>       at :wasm-function[10182]:0x3c0d4e
>       at :wasm-function[12109]:0x4b637b
>       at :wasm-function[12108]:0x4b6095
>       at :wasm-function[10577]:0x3ed282
>       at :wasm-function[10288]:0x3caa9b
>       at :wasm-function[10288]:0x3caab0
>       at :wasm-function[10283]:0x3ca5ba
>       at :wasm-function[10276]:0x3c881e
>       at dynCall_v (:wasm-function[45547]:0xda3ef2)
>       at dynCall_v [Object.dynCall_v] (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:467249)
>       at browserIterationFunc (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:175912)
>       at runIter [Object.runIter] (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:178973)
>       at Browser_mainLoop_runner (WebGL.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:177435) DevTools failed to load
>   SourceMap: Could not load content for
>   chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map:
>   HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME DevTools
>   failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
>   chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
>   blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8
>   Uncaught abort(180) at Error
>       at jsStackTrace (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:22313)
>       at Object.stackTrace (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:22484)
>       at Object.onAbort (https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/2312897/WebGL/Build/UnityLoader.js:4:11118)
>       at abort (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:483549)
>       at :wasm-function[45753]:0xda48f7
>       at :wasm-function[22089]:0x9023d7
>       at :wasm-function[24498]:0x95f899
>       at :wasm-function[22992]:0x93c06c
>       at dynCall_iiiii (:wasm-function[45533]:0xda3cc0)
>       at Object.dynCall_iiiii (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:458801)
>       at invoke_iiiii (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:335871)
>       at :wasm-function[43654]:0xd4f185
>       at :wasm-function[43125]:0xd37edc
>       at :wasm-function[4225]:0x18b90c
>       at :wasm-function[4224]:0x18b835
>       at :wasm-function[10198]:0x3c205a
>       at :wasm-function[10182]:0x3c0d4e
>       at :wasm-function[12109]:0x4b637b
>       at :wasm-function[12108]:0x4b6095
>       at :wasm-function[10577]:0x3ed282
>       at :wasm-function[10288]:0x3caa9b
>       at :wasm-function[10288]:0x3caab0
>       at :wasm-function[10283]:0x3ca5ba
>       at :wasm-function[10276]:0x3c881e
>       at dynCall_v (:wasm-function[45547]:0xda3ef2)
>       at Object.dynCall_v (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:467249)
>       at browserIterationFunc (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:175912)
>       at Object.runIter (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:178973)
>       at Browser_mainLoop_runner (blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8:177435)
>   DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
>   chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map:
>   HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME DevTools
>   failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
>   chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
>   29cf55a5c5-c403-41ef-aab8-de035b7ea92b:8 An abnormal situation has
>   occurred: the PlayerLoop internal function has been called
>   recursively. Please contact Customer Support with a sample project so
>   that we can reproduce the problem and troubleshoot it.  (Filename: 
>   Line: 377)

**If you need the Unity Launcher js. code - I can't involve it here because it has too many letters, priv.**

---

Things I've tried:

- rebuilding the project
- running it locally in Firefox, which usually worked, but the same error is 
  displayed...
- updating Unity to the last version
- making another, but very small project and building it WebGL - worked!!! I 
  don't know how to make so the big project works, any suggestions...?

**Please help!!!**

Comment: Is there any more information in the browser's javascript console like the error suggests? (F12 to bring up in chrome)

Comment: Yes, there is. I edited my post so you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this post but answering it now so if someone has this problem once again it will not confuse so much. I was basically using a dreamlo custom leaderboard in the game and it crashed for a simple reason. Paid SSL was needed for WebGL and I completely missed the point. Dumb.

[image: Proof]

Hope I can help someone if anyone got lost like me these days...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this still matters, but here is an answer anyways. We were able to make sure this issue occurred almost never again. We are still looking at enhancing this because from time to time the error pops up anyway.

### 1. In Unity

- Make sure to updated Unity. The last version seems to handle this better.
- Allocate more memory. In our specific use-case we could really use some more memory (`-s WASM_MEM_MAX=1024MB`).

### 2. In JS

- We made sure to quit Unity every time (in our Angular SPA!). Since there is a service worker that can easily serve Unity again, we always delete the instance.

```
    this.gameInstance
        .Quit()
        .then(() => {
            // Do whatever your app needs here
            this.gameInstance = null;
            this.playState$.next(null);
        })
        .catch(() => {
        console.log("Quitting Unity wasn't a success ");
        });
```

That made things more stable. Hope it can help.

Comment: Lol posted May answered 5 months later but still awesome

Comment: where to do this `-s WASM_MEM_MAX=1024MB` ? I mean in which file write this or where is the setting for change this

Comment: You can work in a folder 'editor' so it is not inside the build, create a C# script that sets the PlayerSettings. Then something along the lines of `PlayerSettings.WebGL.memorySize = 2048;`.

Answer (score 0):

WebGl => publishing Settings => enableExceptions => fullwithout StackTrace

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).